# Connecting to MongoLab database from localhost

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to connecting to a database created under my mongolab account.  I am running this subsequent code on localhost.  It runs for 10-20 seconds before giving me either this error: `[Error: failed to connect to [gmail.com>:27017]]` or this error: `connection error: { [MongoError: auth failed] name: 'MongoError', ok: 0, errmsg: 'auth failed', code: 18 }`

```
var mongoose   = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://<myUserName>:<myPassword>@ds011863.mlab.com:11863/myDBName'); // connect to our database

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
  // we're connected!
  console.log('mongo connected!');
});
```

Are there any inherent problems with attempting to connect to mongoLab's hosted DB's through localhost on port 8080?  I have been through much of mongoLab's trouble-shooting and cannot see what the cause of this error can be.

Comment: The authentication is getting failed. Recheck your password/username.

Comment: i have checked several times.  I created a new user to make sure I wasn't simply forgetting the password and still gets the auth error.

Comment: I solve it!  I was following a year old tutorial online which prescribed a package.json consisting of a Version 3 mongoose.  `npm install --save --save-exact mongoose@4.1.9`  cleared the errors up.